# AndroidAnnotations does not launch intent (in a specific case)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-annotations

I have a `switch()` where depending of item the extras are set in the same Generated Activity by Android Annotations:

```
// this is a switch
case GlobalSearchItemDTO.TYPE_CATEGORIA:
     ProductosActivity_.intent(context)
     .idCategoria(globalSearchEvent.globalSearchItem.getId())
     .flags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
          | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
     .start(); // <-- enters and launch the activity
     break;
case GlobalSearchItemDTO.TYPE_PRODUCTO:
     ProductosActivity_.intent(context)
     .idProducto(globalSearchEvent.globalSearchItem.getId())
     .flags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
          | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
     .start(); // <-- enters but nothing happens
     break;
```

But there is something strange, when i launch the `TYPE_CATEGORIA` case the `ProductosActivity_` is launched rightly.

In the exactly same situation but with the `TYPE_PRODUCTO` case, the `ProductosActivity_` is not getting launched.

YES i debugged code and each case enters rightly in the respective situation

YES even the debugger highlight line touch the `.start()` line in the `TYPE_PRODUCTO` case but nothing is happening

YES the code is already updated with the debugger

NO messages, no errors, no warnings

I'm missing something with Android Annotations?

I have tried with `.get()` to set an intent var and then launch natively the intent.

Answer (score 0):

It only worked if i also setted the other @Extra variable :|

```
// this is a switch
case GlobalSearchItemDTO.TYPE_CATEGORIA:
     ProductosActivity_.intent(context)
     .idCategoria(globalSearchEvent.globalSearchItem.getId())
     .flags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
          | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
     .start(); // <-- enters and launch the activity
     break;
case GlobalSearchItemDTO.TYPE_PRODUCTO:
     ProductosActivity_.intent(context)
     // and this is a shit.ch
     // seriously Android Annotations?
     .idCategoria(globalSearchEvent.globalSearchItem.getId())
     .idProducto(globalSearchEvent.globalSearchItem.getId())
     .flags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
          | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
     .start(); // <-- now enters and launch the activity
     break;
```

I have to say that i dont need the second variable for the logic bisness :|

if i put .idCategoria(null) the bug is still there, so i had to set a value even when i dont need that variable :/